# Get random time objects between certain hours in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I would want a method that:

```
def time_between(from, to)
  ***
end

time_between 10.am.of_today, 3.pm.of_today # => 1pm Time object
time_between 10.am.of_today, 3.pm.of_today # => 3pm Time object
time_between 10.am.of_today, 3.pm.of_today # => 10:30am Time object
# I mean random
```

There are two questions here: how to implement `***`? and how to implement `x.pm.of_today`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ruby 1.9.3

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/all'

def random_hour(from, to)
  (Date.today + rand(from..to).hour + rand(0..60).minutes).to_datetime
end

puts random_hour(10, 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a first try:

```
def time_between(from, to)
  today = Date.today.beginning_of_day
  (today + from.hours)..(today + to.hours).to_a.sample
end
```

Although it works like:

```
time_between(10, 15) # => a random time between 10 am and 3 pm
```

I think is enough, but I'll be open for better solutions.

Answer (score -1):

To get the random time slot you will need to calculate the distance between the two times.  Get a random value with that distance span.  And finally add it to your from time.

Something like: (but I am not going to test it)

```
def time_between(from, to)
  if from > to
    time_between(to, from)
  else
    from + rand(to - from)
  end
end
```

As for creating a DSL for time. You could look at how Rails does it. But to get something like what you are wanting.  Just create a class that represents the hours in the day.  Instantiate it with the am or pm call on a Fixnum. Then write the methods for `of_today` (and any others that you would want).

```
class Fixnum
  def am
    TimeWriter.new(self)
  end

  def pm
    TimeWriter.new(self + 12)
  end
end

class TimeWriter
  MINUTES_IN_HOUR = 60
  SECONDS_IN_MINUTE = 60
  SECONDS_IN_HOUR = MINUTES_IN_HOUR * SECONDS_IN_MINUTE

  def initialize hours
    @hours = hours
  end

  def of_today
    start_of_today + (hours * SECONDS_IN_HOUR)
  end

  private

  attr_reader :hours

  def start_of_today
    now = Time.now
    Time.new(now.year, now.month, now.day, 0, 0)
  end
end
```

You should add some error handling for hours more than 24.

Comment: By `MILLISECONDS_IN_SECOND`, did you mean `SECONDS_IN_MINUTE`?

Answer (score -1):

This code respects minutes and hours as input.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/all'

def random_time(from, to)
  from_arr = from.split(':')
  to_arr   = to.split(':')
  now      = Time.now
  rand(Time.new(now.year, now.month, now.day, from_arr[0], rom_arr[1])..Time.new(now.year, now.month, now.day, to_arr[0], to_arr[1]))
end

puts random_time('09:15', '18:45')
```

Another short way to do the same:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/all'

def random_time(from, to)
  now      = Time.now
  rand(Time.parse(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT#{from}:00%z"))..Time.parse(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT#{to}:00%z")))
end

puts random_time('09:15', '18:45')
```